# bash: capture '\*' in a command line

Tags: bash

```
function abc ()
{
   echo "You typed exactly this: $1"
}
```

Now run it:

```
myprompt$ abc abc\*
```

And I get:

```
You typed exactly this: abc*
```

I'm writing a function in which I need to capture the entire argument, including the backslash, for future use. Can it be done? I've tried every combination of quotes and 'set's and nothing keeps the backslash there. I know I can escape it, but then the argument as typed would not be identical to the argument as echoed. Note that you get the argument back perfectly via 'history'. How can I capture it inside my function, backslash and asterisk and all?

Comment: If you need the backslash then you're [goofing up your quoting somewhere else](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 3):

The shell interprets the `\` character on the command line as an escape character that removes any special meaning from the following character. In order to have a literal `\` in your command line, you need to persuade the shell to ignore the special meaning of `\` which you do by putting a `\` before it. Like this:

```
myprompt$ abc abc\\\*
```

Notice there are three `\` characters. The first tells the shell to ignore the special meaning of the following character - which is the second `\`. The third `\` tells the shell to ignore the special meaning of the `*`.

Another way to persuade the shell not to interpret the `\` as an escape character is to put your argument in single quotes. Like this:

```
myprompt$ abc 'abc\*'
```

Comment: Right, but all of the above result an imperfect capture of the entire argument since something is always stripped off. What I'm saying is that the entire arument is saved to the history list, so somewhere, some how, bash knows how to treat an argument absolutely literaly, and I'm wondering if I could somehow capture that ability.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the arguments exactly as typed.  Bash evaluates them before your function ever sees them.  You'll have to escape or quote it.

```
abc abc\\*
abc 'abc\*'
```

Comment: Fast answers :-) Hey, how do I start a new line in the answer box? When I hit enter it posts it. How do I start a new paragrpah?  Anyway, what you are saying is that it can't be done? But if that is so, how does the history get it saved perfectly?

Comment: The comment box is intended to be a single line, so hitting enter submits instead of inserting a return.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you can't get in the function the exact arguments as they appear on the line.  Either you can escape the characters that need it, in which case you won't see the backslashes, or you can quote it,  but you won't see the quotes from inside your function.  The history gets saved as it appears because it is saved from within the bash binary, before it is evaluated.

Comment: Ok, I'll just accept that what I want to do can't be done.  Thanks gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

You could always take the shotgun vs fly approach and implement your own shell. :)

Or tone it down a bit and find a shell that supports the input mechanism you want.

Note that you would have to change your login settings to utilize a "verbatim-shell".

Comment: I'm not _quite_ ready for that ;-) I think for now I'll just do a search and replace to reinsert the backslash. But one might have thought that bash could have some sort of switch or 'set' that would direct it to leave a command line untouched for situations where that is desired. 'set -o litteralline' or something.

Answer (score 1):

All,

It looks like it is possible to capture an exact command line within a function. 
As I suspected, 'history' gives us a way:

```
function exact_line ()
{
str1=`history 1`
str2=($str1)
str3=
# This isn't very elegant, all I want to do is remove the 
# line count from the 'history' output. Tho this way I do
# have surplus spaces removed as well:
for ((i=1; ; i++))
do
    str3="$str3 ${str2[$i]}"
    if [ -z ${str2[$i]} ]; then break; fi
done
echo -e "Your exact command line was:\n\n$str3"
}
```

Thoughts? Can this be improved?

Comment: You could use sed, awk, or a lot of other things to improve the "field 3 and later" logic here. Perhaps `foo="$(history 1)" ; cut -d' ' -f2- <<<"$foo"` which beats yours by not losing whitespace, or `foo=($(history 1)) ; echo "${foo[@]:1}"` if whitespace does not matter to you.